# How to give numbers to the result after executing the query in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with some 100 records and Total is the one of the colum in the table.I am arranging the rows in the table in the DESC order with the following query.

```
Select Name,Total from tbl_one group by Toal DESC
```

Now my requirment is after getting this result I need to give number to each record starting from first. like

```
John  500 1
Sam   490 2
David 480 3 and till 100
```

Please suggest me the best way of doing this. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: The query as posted is incorrect and will produce an error when executed. There's no `Toal` column, even if your `GROUP BY Total` you cannot select `Name`.

Comment: Select Name,Total,Row_number()OVER(PARTITION BY Total ORDER BY Total DESC ) RN from tbl_one group by Toal DESC

Comment: Can you explain why did you accept incorrect answer?

Comment: it was my mistake Giorgi i was about to accept John Bell answer accepted by scroll mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `ROW_NUMBER` window function:

```
select Name, Total, Row_Number() Over(Order By Total DESC) as RowIndex
from tbl_one 
order by RowIndex
```

PS: in `Sql Server` you call it `ROW` not `RECORD`.

Comment: Gues this approach will fail cause of use of "Index" reserved word

Comment: Just a note on your PS. In *any* RDBMS, entries into a database *should* be referred to as rows. But we all know that records is a common synonym.

Comment: Hmm, Ive got the downvote on answer which is correct :)

Comment: Even i got downvoted for the question dont know the exact reason

Answer (score 2):

Your query will not work. But this is the method used to select an enumerating column:

```
SELECT Name, Total, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Total DESC) AS RN
FROM tbl_one
ORDER BY RN ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`row_number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) window function:

```
SELECT   Name, Total, ROW_NUMBNER() OVER (ORDER BY Total)
FROM     tbl_one
ORDER BY Toal DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  Name,
  Total,
  Index = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [Total] ORDER BY [Total])
FROM tbl_one
```

To retain the grouping

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @startnum INT=400
DECLARE @endnum INT=1400
;
WITH gen AS (
    SELECT @startnum AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num+10 FROM gen WHERE num + 1<=@endnum 
)
SELECT 'Some name',num,ROW_NUMBER()OVER( ORDER BY num DESC) FROM gen order by num desc
option (maxrecursion 10000)
```